# What is wrong with this command piping curl to jq?

Tags: bash, shell-script, jq

I'm trying to make a bash script written for BSD work on Linux, in case that's relevant. Now I'm stumbling over this line:

```
json="$(sudo -u "${vpnUser}" -- curl --interface "${adaptorName}" --get --insecure --silent --show-error --fail --location --max-time "${curlMaxTime}" --data-urlencode "token=${authToken}" "https://${gatewayAddress}:19999/getSignature" | jq -Mre)"
```

I've echo'ed the values of the variables from the script and they look fine. Then I replaced the variables with the values. Then jq seems to complain about a syntax error (generic `Usage:` output) and curl, I assume, says `(23) Failed writing body`.
If a just run the command like `sudo -u ... | jq -Mre` it prints what looks like a JSON file.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367127/combine-pipe-and-redirect-on-curl-and-jq

Comment: ... further discussion here [Write output to a file after piped to jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48964305/write-output-to-a-file-after-piped-to-jq). If you want it to work inside the command substitution, add an explicit filter ex. `jq -Mre '.'`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind! Had an Irish Coffee and looked into `jq` a bit, and got curious why the author would pipe the output through a parser which basically doesn't do anything to the data, it only formats it into a more readable, multi-line output. Removing everything after `|` helped.

Comment: `bash` is `bash` independent of OS. Other commands may vary, mind, but probably not `jq` either

Comment: I would just like to point out that Answers are not the right place for further questions. If you believe it's a pertinent aspect of *this* question, then it should be edited into the Question. If it's a separate question, it should be a separate Question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `jq` releases before 1.6 required a *filter* to run.  The most simple filter is the identity filter which produces the same output as the input.  This is written as a single dot in `jq`.

To get the code to work:

```bash
json=$( ... | jq -r -e . )
```

As for the options that are used with `jq`:

- The `-M` option is the same as `--monochrome-output` and simply requests non-colorised output.  This is the default when `jq` isn't writing to a terminal, so the option can most likely be dropped.
- The `-r` option is the same as `--raw-output`.  When `jq` outputs *bare strings* (not JSON structures containing strings), the strings will be decoded.  This means the outputted strings will not be quoted and will have special character sequences like `\n`, `\t` and `\"` expanded.  This option can *not* be removed if the input to `jq` is a set of JSON-encoded strings that are required to be decoded.
- The `-e` option is the same as `--exit-status`.  This option makes `jq` exit with an exit status that reflects the last evaluated value.  This means the command exits with a *failure* if the final result is `null` or `false`.  If the script is running with the `errexit` shell option activated, a non-zero exit status from `jq` here would terminate the script, which means that this option also can't be removed without knowing more about the script in which the command occurs.

I'm guessing that the use of `jq` here is simply to pretty-print the `curl` result.  It is possible that the original author just copied the three options from someplace without giving them any real thought (the inclusion of `-M` suggests this), but it is equally likely that they might depend on the exit status of `jq` to terminate the script.